# Page doesn't load after .htaccess redirect with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently hosted my website on 000webhost.com and once I hosted it, I logged in to check its working. When I click on a link such as message or profile that contains three parameters such as url, id and ref, the page gets redirected but the profile/message page doesn't load.

For example, the link is : example.com/profile/Sagar-Chauhan/123456/p. On clicking it, it gets redirected but the url show something like this
www.example.com/?url=sagar-chauhan&id=123456&ref=p rather than www.example.com/profile/Sagar-Chauhan/1234656/p

The following is my .htaccess code.

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 Options -Indexes
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

 RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ profile.php?url=$1&id=$2&ref=$3 [L]
 RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ profile.php?url=$1&id=$2&ref=$3 [L]


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your directives is incorrect. Use it as below instead:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite profile/x/x/x to profile.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ profile.php?url=$1&id=$2&ref=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Its still not working. I have used the same code which you posted. Its still the same. URL isn't redirecting properly.

Comment: It should be working. Something else must be redirecting you to the old URL.